# Use typing.List or list in a python type hint?

Tags: python, type-hinting

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html has the following example for aliasing:

```
Vector = list[float]
```

So, you can use `list` as a list in a type hint (or at least an alias).

However, the `typing` module also has a `List`.

If I'm defining a function arg type hint, should I use `list` or `List`?

```
def list_len(a_list: list):
    return len(a_list)
```

or

```
def list_len(a_list: List):
    return len(a_list)
```

?

There are other possibilities too (e.g., `Sequence`).  My first question is just `list` or `List`.  My second is, is there somewhere that describes a best practice in this situation?  (For example, use Sequence, or Iterable, or ..)

Comment: Note that interpreting `list[float]` as a type (or at all) is a newly added functionality as of Python 3.9. If version issues might be a concern, it's probably best to stick to List.